# How to manage multiple inserts based on a variable

Tags: php, sql

So basically I have this game where you can choose between 4 classes. Now each class has its own set of items.

This is the way I currently do this. When a player creates a character. 
It's works but it so messy. Is there any better way of doing this? Well, I'm pretty sure there is but how? Could I get some pointers?

```
if ($class == 1) {
INSERT INTO items (playerid, sid, pid, type, count) 
    VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().",101,1,3788,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",102,3,1614,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",103,4,1555,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",104,5,1308,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",105,6,2000,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",106,7,1101,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",107,8,1714,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",108,10,1010,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",109,102,2112,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",110,102,5432,1)");
}

if ($class == 2) {
INSERT INTO items (playerid, sid, pid, type, count) 
    VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().",101,1,2352,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",102,3,3463,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",103,4,1223,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",104,5,5232,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",105,6,2794,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",106,7,1991,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",107,8,1239,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",108,10,1891,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",109,102,1331,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",110,102,3041,1)");
}

if ($class == 3) {
INSERT INTO items (playerid, sid, pid, type, count) 
    VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().",101,1,2352,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",102,3,1255,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",103,4,6236,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",104,5,2352,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",105,6,2364,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",106,7,346,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",107,8,7345,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",108,10,1010,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",109,102,2112,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",110,102,5432,1)");
}

if ($class == 4) {
INSERT INTO items (playerid, sid, pid, type, count) 
    VALUES (".$db->lastInsertId().",101,1,457,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",102,3,1777,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",103,4,1145,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",104,5,1358,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",105,6,2000,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",106,7,1101,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",107,8,4527,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",108,10,1570,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",109,102,2812,1),
    (".$db->lastInsertId().",110,102,5432,1)");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define some array of values for classes. E.g.

```
$class_items = array(
    1 => array(array(101,1,3788,1), array(102,3,1614,1),...),
    2 => array(),
    // etc
);
```

After that you can create queries based on class_id, e.g.

```
$class_id = 1;
$ins_id = $db->lastInsertId();
$query = 'INSERT INTO items (playerid, sid, pid, type, count) 
VALUES ';
foreach ($class_items[$class_id] as $item) {
    $query .= '("' . $ins_id . '", ' . implode(',', $item)  . '), ';
}
```

Comment: Nice! I only have to figure out why it gives me syntax error. ... Bla bla for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2'

Comment: Print `$query` and try execute it in phpMyAdmin for example. Then correct it accordingly.

Comment: Ah seems to be because it adds a comma on the last one INSERT ...... (46, 110,102,2554,1),

Comment: Solved it with rtrim()